# Evaluating boolean with two char variables in c++

Tags: c++

Apologies, a bit of a beginner here:

I'm working on a practice program to determine cost of a long distance call based on hour of the day and day of the week...and I've gotten to my do-while loop and am attempting to use nested branches to split up weekdays with the weekend.

However, when I compile and run, both the if and else if nested statements are skipped no matter if I put in the Chars corresponding to the booleans I'm attempting to evaluate.  I'm struggling to understand what I'm missing here.  The instructions clearly state that the days of the week should be stored in two char variables: Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su.

```
do
{
    //have user input day of week of call
    printf("\nOn what day was the call made? (Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa, or Su) ");
    scanf("%c%c", &day1, &day2);

    //branch for weekday vs weekend vs invalid input
    if (((day1 == 'M') && (day2 == 'o')) || ((day1 == 'T') && (day2 == 'u')) || ((day1 == 'W') && (day2 == 'e')) || ((day1 == 'T') && (day2 == 'h')) || ((day1 == 'F') && (day2 == 'r')))
    {
        //determine if phone call was made at hi or low rate times
        printf("At what time was your call made? (HH MM - with 08 00 representing 8:00 AM and 18 30 representing 6:30 PM) ");
        scanf("%f %f", &call_time_hour, &call_time_minute);
        call_time_hour = call_time_hour + (call_time_minute / 60);

        printf("%f", call_time_hour);
    }
    else if (((day1 == 'S') && (day2 == 'a')) || ((day1 == 'S') && (day2 == 'u')))
    {
        printf("What was the duration of your call? ");
        scanf("%d", &call_duration);

        //calculate total cost of call
        cost_of_call = call_duration * 0.15;

        printf("%s %.2lf", "The cost of this call was $", cost_of_call);
    }
    calls_made--;
    printf("%d", calls_made);
}while (calls_made > 0);
```

So, for example, when I compile and run the program and enter "Sa" as the day that the call was made, it then moved directly to the 'calls_made--' step.

Comment: This looks more like C. Is this C?

Comment: No, this is c++

Comment: In C++ you should use [std::cout](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) and [std::cin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin).

Comment: I'm prepping for a test and we are instructed to use both cout/cin and printf/scanf.  This particular practice problem indicated that we should use printf/scanf if possible.

Comment: In C++ program you are able to use `printf/scanf` in any case as well as `cout/cin`.
But in C you can use `printf/scanf` only.

Comment: @boriaz50 disagree with *you should*. It's a possibility but there are valid reasons to avoid stream I/O

Comment: @M.M Please, give me some links. It's very interesting for me.

Comment: @Michael What about your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because previous `scanf`. Debug and look what characters are really scanned. I'm sure that `day1` would be `'\n'`.

In this case clear the input stream before scanning the day of week:

```
while (getchar() != '\n');
```